# determination of length of data set

Tags: r

When I read in the `Auto` data set in `ISLR` package, it would appear at first glance that there are 397 observations. I determined this using the `tail()` function. In actuality there are 392 observations. How can I neatly figure out which observations are missing?  I need a way to check the sequence of numbers at far left of the output.

Comment: `?setdiff` maybe - e.g. `setdiff(1:5, c(1,2,4,5))` returns `3`

Comment: > setdiff(1:397,row.names(Auto))
[1]  33 127 331 337 355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nrow(Auto)` indicates that there are really 392 observations, as does `?Auto`:

> Gas mileage, horsepower, and other information for 392 vehicles.

The documentation also says

> The orginal (sic) data contained 408 observations but 16 observations
>        with missing values were removed.

Just guessing, but presumably 5 of the missing observations were within the 'body' of the data and the other 11 were at the end ... to see where the row numbers are non-sequential, try

```
setdiff(1:397,rownames(Auto))
[1]  33 127 331 337 355
```

Not quite as directly useful, but

```
which(diff(as.numeric(rownames(Auto)))>1)
```

might also be handy.

Comment: If this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.

Comment: Excellent reply Thank you.